# Yarn.lock in a team via git

Tags: yarnpkg

A quick question about yarn and yarn.lock in a team setting.  When someone updates yarn.lock in git, what is the procedure for developers?

Does yarn automatically figure out that the lock file is newer than node_modules and "figure it out", or do people remove their local node_modules and rerun yarn install?

Answer (score 0):

Yarn won't do any check on `node_modules` folder when `yarn.lock` is updated via VCS.

To align `node_modules` folder with the dependencies listed in `yarn.lock`, there is no need to delete the folder. Run [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/#toc-default-command) command instead.